# Using Query In Post Type Archives

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm using the script below to call post from a certain category in the sidebar. It pulls from all post type on the homepage and on the single post page, but when it comes down to the post type archive pages it doesn't show but only from that post type archive in which you are viewing.....I want it to show from all post types not matter what post type archive you are viewing.

```
<?php
$queryObject = new  Wp_Query( array(
        'showposts' => 4,
        'post_type' => array('pretty-little-liars', 'revenge', 'once-upon-a-time','scandal'),
        'category_name' => celebrity,
            'orderby' => 1,
        ));
// The Loop!
if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
 ?>
<?php
while ($queryObject->have_posts()){
    $queryObject->the_post();
    ?>
```

How do i get it to show post from all post type by category on the post type archive page?

Comment: Is the `category` taxonomy registered for all of the listed custom post types, `pretty-little-liars`, `revenge`, `once-upon-a-time`, and `scandal`? Do posts of all of these custom post types have posts with the `celebrity` term in the category taxonomy?

Comment: Yes, it is registered and, yes they have post under the category `celebrity`

Comment: Also: replace `'showposts'` with `'posts_per_page'`. The former was deprecated some time ago.

Comment: I did, but is there ant solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Change it from:

```
    'category_name' => celebrity,
    'orderby' => 1,
```

into

```
    'category_name' => 'celebrity',
    'orderby' => 'date', // or something else
```

Otherwise `celebrity` will be treated as a constant name, not a string. Also, you can't order by `1`, you have to use one of the [ordering parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: tried this and it's still doing the same thing, It's only showing from that one post type archive instead of all post type archives

Comment: it's still not shoing in the archives.... go to Tv-cafe.com and notice the "Latest In Celebrity" and the "Latest Videos" then go to Tv-cafe.com/one-upon-a-time and notice that they aren't showing from all post types

Comment: So, when you go to the archive for **Post Type A**, do you also want to show **Post Type B** and **Post Type C**? That's a little odd, but just add `'post_type' => 'any'` or `'post_type' => array('post-type-a', 'post-type-b', 'post-type-c')` to the arguments array.

Comment: neither of those otions worked :( @Simon

Comment: I see now that it was already in you initial arguments, sorry about that. I just tested running a query using `array( 'post_type' => 'any', 'category_name' => 'some_cat' )` and it worked out fine, as did using an array of post types. Perhaps all post types you are querying doesn't have the default `category` taxonomy registered (you need to do that manually), or perhaps the posts are not assigned to the specific category term you are querying?

Comment: the have to be because they are shwing on the homepage and the single post page @simon

Comment: That's odd, as the query worked fine when I tested it. The only advice I can give is to try to simplify your code as much as possible and try to isolate what is causing the issue. I often find it useful to leave out most of the query arguments initially, re-adding them one at a time to understand where the conflict/problem stems from. During such testing it is often useful running `var_dump($queryObject->request);` to verify that the generated SQL is correct, and try running it manually at times.